# How to match the results back to an array

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I have an array of objects.  The object has two properties a value and an index.

I use a linq to entities query with the contains keyword to bring back all results in a table that match up to value.

Now here is the issue... I want to match up the results to the object index...

what is the fastest best way to perform this.  I can add properties to the object.

It is almost like I want the query results to return this:

```
index = 1;
value = "searchkey"
queryvalue = "query value"
```

Comment: It would really help if you could provide a small sample of data, a sample search string, and the results you expect based on that sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question I think I can assume that you have the following variables defined:

- `Lookup[]` (You look-up array)
- `IEnumerable<Record>` (The results returned by your query)

... and the types look roughly like this:

```
public class Lookup
{
    public int Index { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

public class Record
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
    /* plus other fields */
}
```

Then you can solve your problem in a couple of ways.

First using an anonymous type:

```
var matches
    = from r in records
      join l in lookups on r.Value equals l.Value
      group r by l.Index into grs
      select new
      {
          Index = grs.Key,
          Records = grs.ToArray(),
      };
```

The other two just use standard LINQ `GroupBy` & `ToLookup`:

```
IEnumerable<IGrouping<int, Record>> matches2
    = from r in records
      join l in lookups on r.Value equals l.Value
      group r by l.Index;

ILookup<int, Record[]> matches3
    = matches2.ToLookup(m => m.Key, m => m.ToArray());
```

Do these solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Just a shot in the dark as to what you need, but the LINQ extension methods can handle the index as a second paramter to the lambda functions. IE:

someCollection.Select( (x,i) => new { SomeProperty = x.Property, Index = i } );